# Return boolean value from CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a 5 seconds count down timer and I need to detect the amplitude of acceleration within the duration. If the amplitude meet the statement, a true will be return. However, due to the void method OnTick and also it is an inner class, I couldn't return or pass any value to outer class.

```
public boolean low_high_Detection(final double ampA) {
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            final double low_TH = 9.0, high_TH = 10.5;
            boolean lying_on_floor = false;
            if(ampA > low_TH && ampA <high_TH)
            {
                lying_on_floor = true;
            }
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(detect.getBaseContext(), "5 seconds dectection over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.start();

    if (lying_on_floor == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Anyone can suggest me how can I fix this method? Or there is another way to deal with it.

Comment: make boolean lying_on_floor = false; as a  class field.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry my oo concept is not that good. Is class field means the getter and setter? @Deepakkaku

Comment: No just declare it outside a function within a class. that way it becomes a class field which has its scope in all its functions

Comment: Oh great, thanks. By any chance do you know how to pass ampA into the CountDownTimer class? The ampA value will keep changing. @Deepakkaku

Comment: similar to the boolean should work. make it a class field

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with an anonymous class as a listener.

Declare an interface which actues as a listener.

```
public interface LowHightDetectionListener {
   void onDetected(boolean result);
}
```

Then, **to call this method** and pass an instance of this listener to the method `low_high_Detection()`

```
low_high_Detection(ampA, new LowHightDetectionListener {
   @Override
   public void onDetected(boolean result) {
      // Process the result
   }
});
```

Here you get the "returned" value.

To return the desired value inside the `low_high_Detection()` method you need to call the listener.

```
public void low_high_Detection(final double ampA, final LowHightDetectionListener callback) {
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        final double low_TH = 9.0, high_TH = 10.5;
        boolean lying_on_floor = false;
        if(ampA > low_TH && ampA <high_TH) {
            lying_on_floor = true;
            callback.onDetected(true); // EXAMPLE OF RETURNING VALUE INSIDE AN ANONYMOUS CLASS
         }
      }

      public void onFinish() {
        Toast.makeText(detect.getBaseContext(), "5 seconds dectection over",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }.start();

   if (lying_on_floor == true) {
     callback.onDetected(true);
     return;
   }
   callback.onDetected(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can I ask how should I pass instance of listener to method? Like at which part? Actually the lying_on_floor == true, this variable is not accessible too due to inner class. And there is a mistake on parameter, the ampA cannot be final, there is some mistake on auto correction atm which I didn't notice. Do you have any idea to make this method works?

Comment: You should call this method with this way: 
low_high_Detection(ampA, new LowHightDetectionListener {
   @Override
   public void onDetected(boolean result) {
      // Process the result
   }
}); In the answer is the code example with the call. And ampA should be final if it's accessed from inside a anonymous class.

Comment: I need more context to know how fix or improve this method.

Comment: I think I get it on the calling part and I just realized you change this method to void. But there are 2 more things, first, the bool lying_on_floor in the if statement is not accessible. Secondly, the ampA actually need to pass in continuously from sensors for 5 seconds for checking, it can't be final isn't?

Comment: Share more code in order to understand better your problem.